# Jenkins pipeline unable to execute docker commands in pods

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have Jenkins running in my GKE cluster and I am trying to deploy some code from my GitHub on the same cluster. I am trying to execute docker commands inside a pod with "docker:19" image. My pipeline configuration is inside the Jenkinsfile in my repository and I'm executing a "Pipeline from SCM" build. However, the console output of the build looks like several pods are being created and terminated constantly.

Build logs

```
Started by user Aayush
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/AayushPathak/fullstack-app-devops/
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] readTrusted
Obtained buildPod.yaml from git https://github.com/AayushPathak/fullstack-app-devops/
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Created Pod: default/multi-crud-39-lx36n-8src2-xrqmf
default/multi-crud-39-lx36n-8src2-xrqmf Container docker was terminated (Exit Code: 0, Reason: Completed)
Still waiting to schedule task
‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘multi-crud_39-lx36n’
Created Pod: default/multi-crud-39-lx36n-8src2-d8fr9
default/multi-crud-39-lx36n-8src2-d8fr9 Container docker was terminated (Exit Code: 0, Reason: Completed)
Created Pod: default/multi-crud-39-lx36n-8src2-rf4vw
default/multi-crud-39-lx36n-8src2-rf4vw Container docker was terminated (Exit Code: 0, Reason: Completed)
Created Pod: default/multi-crud-39-lx36n-8src2-ndh14
default/multi-crud-39-lx36n-8src2-ndh14 Container docker was terminated (Exit Code: 0, Reason: Completed)
Created Pod: default/multi-crud-39-lx36n-8src2-nbj0f
default/multi-crud-39-lx36n-8src2-nbj0f Container docker was terminated (Exit Code: 0, Reason: Completed)
.
.
.
.
```

Here's how Jenkins is set up inside the cluster

kubectl setup

```
aayush_pathak15@cloudshell:~/continuous-deployment-on-kubernetes/jenkins (multi-crud)$ kubectl get svc
NAME                                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
cd-jenkins                                      ClusterIP      10.3.248.115   <none>         8080/TCP                     2d22h
cd-jenkins-agent                                ClusterIP      10.3.243.156   <none>         50000/TCP                    2d22h
kubernetes                                      ClusterIP      10.3.240.1     <none>         443/TCP                      2d22h
my-release-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.3.241.83    34.122.66.93   80:31844/TCP,443:30350/TCP   2d4h
my-release-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.3.241.55    <none>         443/TCP                      2d4h
```

I believe I have set up the kubernetes cloud correctly

[image]

Below are my Jenkinsfile and the Pod YAML inside which I want to execute my build

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    SHA = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse HEAD")
  }
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      idleMinutes 5
      yamlFile 'buildPod.yaml'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('test') {
      steps {
        container('docker') {
          sh 'docker build -t aayushpathak/frontend-test -f ./client/Dockerfile.dev ./client'
          sh 'docker run aayushpathak/frontend-test -e CI=true npm test'
        }
      }
    }

    stage('build-push-production-images') {
      steps {
        container('docker') {
          sh 'docker build -t aayushpathak/frontend-test -f ./client/Dockerfile.dev ./client'
          sh 'docker run aayushpathak/frontend-test -e CI=true npm test'
        }
      }
    }

    stage('deploy') {
      environment {
        GC_HOME = '$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
        GC_KEY = credentials('jenkins-secret')
      }

      steps {
        container('docker') {
          sh("rm -r -f /root/google-cloud-sdk")
          sh("curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash > /dev/null;")
          sh("${GC_HOME}/gcloud components update kubectl")
          sh("${GC_HOME}/gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${GC_KEY}")
          sh("${GC_HOME}/kubectl apply -f k8s")
          sh("${GC_HOME}/kubectl set image deployments/server-deployment server=aayushpathak/fullstack-server:${SHA}")
          sh("${GC_HOME}/kubectl set image deployments/client-deployment client=aayushpathak/fullstack-client:${SHA}")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

buildPod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: docker
      image: docker:19
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumeMounts:
        - name: docker
          mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
  volumes:
    - name: docker
      hostPath:
        path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Jenkins, however there might be 2 issues.

**Issue 1**

Form Kubernetes points of view YAML is incorrect. When I used your YAML, Ive got an error like below:

```
$ kubectl apply -f tst.yaml
error: error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "/v1, Resource=pods", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=Pod"
Name: "", Namespace: "default"
```

After adding `metadata.name` it worked.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: docker-container
spec:
  containers:
    - name: docker
      image: docker:19
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumeMounts:
        - name: docker
          mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
  volumes:
    - name: docker
      hostPath:
        path: /var/run/docker.sock
$ kubectl apply -f docker.yaml
pod/docker-container created
```

**Issue 2**

Your pod is getting restarted over and over as container exits when its main process exits. As your pods doing nothing it created pod, and as nothing more is to do it terminated it instantly.

**Output:**

```
$ kubectl get po
NAME               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
docker-container   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4          2m32s
```

To keep pod you can for example use `sleep` command or `sleep infinity`. More details and options can be found in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/determine-reason-pod-failure/).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: docker-container
spec:
  containers:
    - name: docker
      image: docker:19
      command: ["/bin/sh"]         #To run command inside container
      args: ["-c", "sleep 3600"]   #Specified sleep command
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumeMounts:
        - name: docker
          mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
  volumes:
    - name: docker
      hostPath:
        path: /var/run/docker.sock
        
$ kubectl apply -f docker-sleep.yaml
pod/docker-container created
```

**Output:**

```
$ kubectl get po
NAME               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
docker-container   1/1     Running   0          2m15s
```

As in your logs occurs entry like:

```
Created Pod: default/multi-crud-39-lx36n-8src2-d8fr9
default/multi-crud-39-lx36n-8src2-d8fr9 Container docker was terminated (Exit Code: 0, Reason: Completed)
```

I'd say root cause is `Issue 2` as docker don't have anything to do so it finished main process and exit.